# Simple Asterisk PJSIP config for two softphones with messaging and presence

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, pjsip, instant-messaging

My goal is to establish a very simple telephony system with Asterisk 13 and PJSIP, and enable two softphones (i.e. MicroSIP), so they could call each other, text message each other, and know if each other is online or offline.

What should I have on extensions.conf, pjsip.conf, and so on, so I can reach my goal?

I have been looking on the web for a simple example of this setup for many days but have not found yet. Information about pjsip on asterisk (for beginners) is scarce on the web. Any help is welcome, even to suggest another kind of software, or any other idea. My server is running on Ubuntu 14.

Thank you,
Marcio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so firstly i would recommend learning the basics of asterisk configuration. How to configure the extensions.conf and sip.conf (not pjsip.conf) is explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZVwbUQNrLw) youtube video (if you already set up PJSIP and Asterisk you can skip to 10:00, here the configuration is explained). I think this is the easiest part.

Now writing you'r own soft phones is another step, here i recommend reading [this](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/index.html) documentation, since it is easier to program on high-level API's. This documentation is in it's alpha but still they go through it step by step and have many snippets.

Comment: MrNice, we are said to not use comments to say thank you. Anyway, thank you. About the question: WhatsApp has become a better solution for our needs than SIP.